# Multilevel Push Menu with Bootstrap3

Tags: angularjs, menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, submenu

I would love to find something similar to this multilevel push-menu (with overlapping), but for a Bootstrap 3 based site.
Does anyone know about some adaptation of the same?

Whatever Codrops creates is really awesome, but never Bootstrap ready and I am not able to port it myself most of the time.

I would like this to work with AngularJS, ng-repeats, children etc...

The link: [Multilevel Push Menu](http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/index.html)

Comment: Just don't use the Bootstrap navigation. It only allows 1 level of links toggle > child (that's it).

Answer (score 0):

This one maybe?
MultiLevelPushMenu jQuery Plugin implementation, https://github.com/adgsm/multi-level-push-menu

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented the Coderops multi level menu in my own site under bootstrap 3.  My solution might not be exactly what you need as it is a Backbone Marionette App, however there might be something there to get you started.

My HAML for getting the menu DIV nested inside the bootstrap container is

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title>
      = "Mark2"
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}/
    %meta{:name => "fragment", :content => '!'}
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => false
    = javascript_include_tag 'modernizr'
  %body
    .container
      .mp-pusher#mp-pusher
        %nav.mp-menu#mp-menu
        .scroller#scroller
          .scroller-inner
            .row
              .col-md-12
                = yield
  = requirejs_include_tag "app"
```

So I have the menu div inside the bootstrap container and then the rest of the site inside the scroller.

A full write up is on my personal site.

[Multi Level Push Menu In Backbone Marionette And Bootstrap 3](http://mark.stratmann.me/articles/multi-level-push-menu-in-backbone-marionette-and-bootstrap-3-xxx)

Feel free to comment here or on my site if you want more details.